# C++ Kepler's and Newton's Law

Tags: c++, math, physics, sfml

So I have two files. A main file and a nbody file.

What I'm trying to do is use SFML to draw onto a window and basically simulate a galaxial orbit. The constant damn problem I get is that while everything works from a syntax standpoint, all the planets are moving out of scale and completely wonky.

I can't figure out why it's not working.
Please help me sort out the issue..

This here is the nbody file.

```
 #include SFML/Graphics.hpp
 #include SFML/Window.hpp
 #include iostream
 #include cmath
 #include cstring
 class Body:sf::Drawable{
  sf::String file;
  sf::Texture texture;

public:
  double x,y;
  double xvel,yvel,mass,scale,winsize;
  sf::Sprite sprite;
  Body(double _x,double _y,double _xvel, double _yvel, double           _mass,std::string _file,double _scale,double _winsize){
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    xvel = _xvel;
    yvel = _yvel;
    mass = _mass;
    file = _file;
    scale = _scale;

  }
  sf::Sprite Sprite(){
    texture.loadFromFile(file);
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setPosition(x,y);
    return sprite;
  }

  void move(double position, std::vector<Body> galaxy, double time){
    double G = 6.67 * pow(10,-11);
    double Fx=0, Fy=0;

for(double i=0;i<galaxy.size();i++){
  if(position!=i){      
double x1 = x;
double x2 = (galaxy.at(i)).x;
double dx = (x2-x1)*scale;  ////The math here works

double y1 = y;
double y2 = (galaxy.at(i)).y;
double dy = (y2-y1)*scale; /// The math here works

double m2 = (galaxy.at(i)).mass;
double m1 = mass; //results in mass

double r = sqrt((dx * dx)+(dy * dy));
double F = G*m1*m2/(r*r);


Fx += (F*dx)/r;
Fy += (F*dy)/r; 

  }
  xvel += Fx/mass*time;
  yvel += Fy/mass*time;

  x+=xvel/100000;
  y+=yvel/100000;
  Sprite();
}         
  }

 virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states)      const{
   target.draw(sprite,states); //parameters should be in here
  }  
};
```

The main File:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "nbody.cpp"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  void move(double position, std::vector<Body> galaxy,double scale);
  int f;

  std::cin>>f;
  double radius, scale, winsize;
  winsize = 800;

  std::cin>>radius;
  std::cout<<radius<<" \n";
  std::vector<Body> galaxy;

  scale = radius/(winsize/2);  
  for(double i=0;i<f;i++){ 
    double x,y,xv,yv,m;
    std::string name;
    std::cin>>x;
    std::cin>>y;
    std::cin>>xv;
    std::cin>>yv;  
    std::cin>>m;
    std::cin>>name;
    x = x/scale+(winsize/2);
    y = y/scale+(winsize/2);

    std::cout<<x<<" "<<y<< " " << xv << " " << yv<< " "<< m<< "\n";

    Body b(x,y,xv,yv,m,name,scale,winsize);
    galaxy.push_back(b);
  }  

  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(winsize, winsize), "Universe");    
  double time =0;
  while (window.isOpen())
    {
      sf::Event event;
      while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
      if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        window.close();
    }

      window.clear();
      for(double i=0;i<galaxy.size();i++){
    double position = i;
    (galaxy.at(i)).move(position,galaxy,time);  
    sf::Sprite a = (galaxy.at(i).sprite);
    window.draw(a);
      } 
      window.display();
      time +=.1;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

And I have a planets text file that is piped into the function to generate the solar system. The first number is the number of entities, the second is the radius and all the others in each line is the properties of each planets: in order (x,y,xvel,yvel,mass,imagefile)

```
5
2.50e+11
0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  1.9890e+30      sun.gif
 1.4960e+11  0  0.0000e+00  2.9800e+04  5.9740e+24    earth.gif
 2.2790e+11  0           0.0000e+00  2.4100e+04  6.4190e+23     mars.gif
 5.7900e+10  0 0.0000e+00  4.7900e+04  3.3020e+23  mercury.gif
 1.0820e+11  0 0.0000e+00  3.5000e+04  4.8690e+24    venus.gif
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't multiply by scale? I'm assuming that's the constant that shrinks your solar system into screen space. That will totally blow up your integration step below. Multiply the x,y in sprite.SetPosition by it instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is always the same problem:

First compute all the forces, then, when all interactions are accounted for, update the velocities and positions. Mixing this up leads to the later interactions computed increasingly with new positions. This introduces a drift that completely depends on the order of the objects inside your collection.

And for Pete's sake, use something better than symplectic Euler (and I'd think that you were not aware of that). This is acceptable for some quick'n'dirty game physics, but not for semi-scientific purposes. Use at least Verlet or better RK4 or a symplectic 4th order method.

Standard link: [Moving stars around](http://www.artcompsci.org/msa/web/vol_1/v1_web/v1_web.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
  x+=xvel/100000;
  y+=yvel/100000;
```

Should be:

```
  x+=xvel/scale*time;
  y+=yvel/scale*time;
```

Or better yet, keep your x and y in meters for doing physics and do the transformation into screen space only when drawing the sprite.